# Sql Server get first matching value

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have two tables History and Historyvalues:

### History

```
HID(uniqeidentifier) | Version(int)
a1 | 1
a2 | 2
a3 | 3
a4 | 4
```

### Historyvalues

```
HVID(uniqeidentifier) | HID(uniqeidentifier) | ControlID(uniqeidentifier) | Value(string) 
b1 | a1 | c1 | value1 
b2 | a2 | c1 | value2 
b3 | a2 | c2 | value3
```

Now I Need a query where I can get a list with the last historyvalue of each control from a specific Version like:

Get the last values from Version 3 -> receiving ->

```
HVID | ControlID | Value
b2 | c1 | value2
b3 | c2 | value3
```

I tried something like this:

```
Select HVID, ControlId, max(Version), Value from 
(   
    Select HVID, ControlId, Version, Value
    from History inner JOIN
         Historyvalues ON History.HID = Historyvalues.HID
    where Version <= 3  
) as a
group by ControlId
order by Version desc
```

but this does not work.

Are there any ideas?

Thank you very much for your help.

Best regards

Comment: Should `Historyvalues ON History.HID = Historyvalues.HVID` be `HID` not `HVID` ?

Comment: Yes of course you're right, sorry about this. Now it's correct but of course it's still not working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Latest version from each control with your specific Version (`WHERE t1.Version <= 3`)

Query:

**[SQLFIDDLEExample](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/b5ca8/6)**

```
SELECT HVID, ControlId, Version, Value 
FROM
(   
    SELECT t2.HVID, t2.ControlId, t1.Version, t2.Value,
           ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY t2.ControlId ORDER BY t1.Version DESC) as rnk
    FROM History t1 
     JOIN Historyvalues t2 
      ON t1.HID = t2.HID
    WHERE t1.Version <= 3  
) AS a
WHERE a.rnk = 1
ORDER BY a.Version desc
```

Result:

```
| HVID | CONTROLID | VERSION |  VALUE |
|------|-----------|---------|--------|
|   b2 |        c1 |       2 | value2 |
|   b3 |        c2 |       2 | value3 |
```

Answer (score 0):

here is your solution

```
 Select  Historyvalues.HVID,Historyvalues.ControlID,Historyvalues.Value
 from Historyvalues
 inner join History on Historyvalues.hid=History.hid
 where Historyvalues.hvid in (
            select MAX(Historyvalues.hvid) from Historyvalues
        inner join History on Historyvalues.hid=History.hid
        group by ControlID)
```

Comment: Unfortunately this does not work because it Returns only the controlId's and values from the one history HID. If you can see in example above, Version 3 (a3) has no controls. Version 2(a2) has two ControlId's c1 and c2 but Version1(a1) has the controlId c1 as well. So I Need only thecontrolId's and values for the c1 which has the highest historyversion. So if I ask for Version 3, there is the controlid c2 in it (b3) and the higher Version of c1 and this is the b2.

Comment: Like this, I receive the error "The objects "History" and "History" in the FROM clause have the same exposed names. Use correlation names to distinguish them". Could you please help for this again? Thanks a lot.

Comment: Like this, the Version is not relevant anymore. Are you sure with the max(Historyvalues.hvid) because the hvid is a guid? Where is the Version? I Need to ask give me the result for the Version 3 for example. Do you have any idea?

Comment: you just need to keep in mind that your latest version of control to be inserted at last

Comment: Is the max(Historyvalues.hvid) not sorting the id? Is the database itself looking for an insertdate? I don't understand this. If I need the query only for Version 3 and smaller (not Version 4,5,6 etc) is this work like this?